# How do I send data from a GKPlayer to another in a match?

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I would like to send `NSData` from a `GKPlayer` to another in a match. Therefore, the method [`sendDataToAllPlayers(_:withDataMode:error:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKMatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKMatch/sendDataToAllPlayers:withDataMode:error:) would be the most ideal.

```
func sendDataToAllPlayers(data: Int,
    withDataMode Reliable: GKMatchSendDataMode,
    error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool {

    return true
}
```

Though, how can I use the method above to send an `Int` variable?

```
var score:Int = 0
```

Comment: Do you need to convert Int to NSData and Back to int ?

Comment: I probably do. It would be the better solution for my case. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/game-center-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-part-12

Comment: http://www1.in.tum.de/lehrstuhl_1/home/98-teaching/tutorials/508-sgd-ws13-tutorial-multiplayer-games

Comment: https://github.com/jackcook/GCHelper/blob/master/Source/GCHelper.swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version for encapsulating an `Int` (or other type) into or extracting it from`NSData` should work even between devices with different byte orders:

```
// at sender before sending data
let data = NSMutableData()
let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWithMutableData: data)
archiver.encodeInteger(score, forKey: "score")
archiver.finishEncoding()

// at receiver after receiving data
let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: data)
let score = unarchiver.decodeIntegerForKey("score")
unarchiver.finishDecoding()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
extension Int {
    var data: NSData {
        var source = self
        return NSData(bytes: &source, length: sizeof(Int))
    }
}
extension Double {
    var data: NSData {
        var source = self
        return NSData(bytes: &source, length: sizeof(Double))
    }
}
extension NSData {
    var integerValue:Int {
        var result = 0
        getBytes(&result, length: sizeof(Int))
        return result
    }
    var doubleValue:Double {
        var result:Double = 0
        getBytes(&result, length: sizeof(Double))
        return result
    }
}

let myIntegerData = 123.data                 // _NSInlineData
let backToInt = myIntegerData.integerValue   // 123

let myDoubleData = 123.456789.data           // _NSInlineData
let backToDouble = myDoubleData.doubleValue  // 123.456789
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I use this code in the `sendDataToAllPlayers(_:withDataMode:error:) ` method? Thanks again.

Comment: I am not sure if this code is what I am looking for, as it represents a partial answer to my question.

Comment: Have you seen the last link I posted ?

Comment: Thank you for posting the links. The last two are pretty informative. Thank you for posting them. Working on them right now. You surely deserve a +1 from me. Thank you very much.