# How to convert an Int into NSData in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, int, nsdata

In Objective-C I use the following code to

1. Convert an `Int` variable into `NSData`, a packet of bytes.

   ```
   int myScore = 0;
   NSData *packet = [NSData dataWithBytes:&myScore length:sizeof(myScore)];
   ```
2. Use the converted `NSData` variable into a method.

   ```
   [match sendDataToAllPlayers: 
   packet withDataMode: GKMatchSendDataUnreliable 
   error: &error];
   ```

I tried converting the Objective-C code into Swift:

```
var myScore : Int = 0

func sendDataToAllPlayers(packet: Int!,
            withDataMode mode: GKMatchSendDataMode,
            error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool {

            return true
}
```

However, I am not able to convert an `Int` variable into an `NSData` and use it an a method. How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28662828/2303865

Answer (score 70, accepted):

With Swift 3.x to 5.0:

```
var myInt = 77
var myIntData = Data(bytes: &myInt, 
                     count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: myInt))
```

Answer (score 57):

In contemporary versions of Swift, I would do:

```
let score = 1000
let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: score) { Data($0) }
```

```
e8 03 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

And convert that `Data` back to an `Int`:

```
let value = data.withUnsafeBytes {
    $0.load(as: Int.self)
}
```

---

Note, when dealing with binary representations of numbers, especially when exchanging with some remote service/device, you might want to make the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) explicit, e.g.

```
let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: score.littleEndian) { Data($0) }
```

```
 e8 03 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

And convert that `Data` back to an `Int`:

```
let value = data.withUnsafeBytes {
    $0.load(as: Int.self).littleEndian
}
```

Versus big endian format, also known as “network byte order”:

```
let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: score.bigEndian) { Data($0) }
```

```
 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 e8
```

And convert that `Data` back to an `Int`:

```
let value = data.withUnsafeBytes {
    $0.load(as: Int.self).bigEndian
}
```

Needless to say, if you don’t want to worry about endianness, you could use some established standard like JSON (or even XML).

---

For Swift 2 rendition, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28681106/1).

Comment: IMO such `data` won't be portable (should not be transferred without additional metadata) between devices with different byte orders (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662770/how-do-i-send-data-from-a-gkplayer-to-another-in-a-match/28727335#28727335)).

Comment: I actually agree. I just modeled my answer after the [sending data to other players](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW27) discussion in the _Game Center Programming Guide,_ but it does seem more prudent to use archive or plist or some other more robust format.

Comment: You can use `score.bigEndian` or `score.littleEndian` to force the byte order to be of a specific endianness. The data will then be compatible between architectures able to be written on one and read on another.

Comment: I'd suggest `bigEndian`, as this is generally considered to be ["network byte order"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Networking). And is also, obviously, the correct way around ;-)

Answer (score 5):

For any integer type:

```
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    var data: Data {
        let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: self) { Data($0) }
        return data
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let data = 1.data
```

Answer (score 4):

You can convert in this way:

```
var myScore: NSInteger = 0
let data = NSData(bytes: &myScore, length: sizeof(NSInteger))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! May you please tell me how to include `data` into my method? I get `data is not a type` when I code it this way: `func sendDataToAllPlayers(data,`

Comment: You are welcome :)  Sorry, I don't catch your question, what you need to do?

Comment: If you look at the second bullet point of my question there is a code of a function `sendDataToAllPlayers ` Now, I translated that function already but I would like to include the constant `data` you have declared in your answer into my Swift method. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: It seems that Rob's answer is what you are looking, is it true? of I'm missing something?

Answer (score 3):

***Swift 5***, add an other option.

`NSData` is old, still effective

**Write Data:**

```
let buffer = NSMutableData()
let size = MemoryLayout<UInt>.size
let big = 1000
let small = 10
withUnsafeBytes(of: big, { (p) in
      let bufferPointer = p.bindMemory(to: UInt.self)
      if let address = bufferPointer.baseAddress{
             buffer.append(address, length: size)
      }
})

withUnsafeBytes(of: small, { (p) in
      let bufferPointer = p.bindMemory(to: UInt.self)
      if let address = bufferPointer.baseAddress{
           buffer.append(address, length: size)
      }
 })
```

**Read data:**

```
if let d = buffer.copy() as? Data{
     var big: UInt = 0
     var small: UInt = 0
     let size = MemoryLayout<UInt>.size
     let meta = NSData(data: data)
     meta.getBytes(&big, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: size))
     meta.getBytes(&small, range: NSRange(location: size, length: size))

     print("big:", big, "\nsmall:", small)
    //  big: 1000 
    //  small: 10 
}
```

You know the memory layout, the data put in the memory,

Then put them out exactly.

`unsafe` method is *funny*

Answer (score 0):

Use this initializer to convert every Array to Data

```
Data(element: Sequence)
```

example:

```
let myArr     = [12,45,67,898, 100]
let myArrData = Data(myArr)
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the size of Int you are working with, a straight forward approach is to init Data with Sequence of UInt8:

```
let value: Int = 100
let data = Data([UInt8(value)])
// OR
let data = Data([0xFF, 0xFE])
```

Comment: Data([UInt8(value)]) will only let you use numbers > 0 and < 256...

Comment: No doubt, that's why I qualified the answer.