# How to convert bool to NSData

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, nskeyedunarchiver

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680589/how-to-convert-an-int-into-nsdata-in-swift) to convert a `Int` into `NSData`

It says to do this:

```
var foo: Int = 1000
let data = NSData(bytes: &foo, length: sizeof(Int))
```

I was wondering, should I do the same think for converting a `Bool` to `NSData`, like this:

```
 var purchase: Bool = true
 let data = NSData(bytes: &purchase, length: sizeof(Bool))
```

In my case I always know that the `Bool` will be true. Since this is the case, I was wondering if there is a simpler method to convert the value "true" to a `NSData` object.

Some background context:

I am storing this `NSData` value in the keychain with [this library](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess).

I am also going to be convert the `NSData` value back into a bool with `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData`

Comment: try converting bool to int and then convert it into NSData

Comment: I would convert the Bool to a byte, not int.  Then just do a `NSData setBytes`.  Since Bool is a signed char and a char is a byte, there's no conversion...  Just cast it to a byte.

Comment: `NSNumber(booleanLiteral: purchase)` can convert boo to number.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift >= 4 Solution**

we can easily achieve this using `JSONEncoder` cause `Bool` `struct` confirms `Codable` `Typealias`

```
let mBoolValue = true
let boolData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(mBoolValue)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4 Solution**

```
if let isBool = value as? Bool
{
    var valueInInt = Int(NSNumber(value: isBool)) //Convert Bool to Int
    let data = Data(bytes: &valueInInt, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: valueInInt) //Int to Data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try extending Bool with a function that returns NSData

(I don't have my IDE with me right now, so the syntax might not be right)

```
extension Bool {
  func toNSData() -> NSData {
    var data: NSData?
    if ( self.value ) { //not sure if this is the right syntax
      return NSData(bytes: 1, length: sizeof(Int))
    }
    return NSData(bytes: 0, lentgh: sizeOf(Int))
  }
}
```

Then any bool will have NSData representation like so

```
let b: Bool = true
let data: NSData = b.toNSData()
```

I'm still new at this, but I think the above is part of "protocol oriented programming" that apple encourages.